# Problem with tabs on foundation framework

Tags: css, wordpress, tabs, zurb-foundation

I have problem with tabs on foundation on a wordpress theme ...The original code have 4 horizontally tabs and I need to add a fifth element ... but when i add the fifth... the fifth element align vertically under the first tab...

This is the original code:

```
<div class="content row info active" id="panel2">
     <?php query_posts('p=35'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="large-12 columns thu">
<dl class="row content tabs small-6 large-centered columns" data-tab>

 <dd><a href="#cabernetsauvignon"><span class="link">Cabernet Sauvignon</span></a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#merlot"><span class="link">Merlot</span></a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#chardonnay"><span class="link">Chardonnay</span></a></dd>
<dd><a href="#sauvignonblanc"><span class="link">Sauvignon Blanc</span></a></dd></dl>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
             </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns txt">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div> 
    </div> 
            <?php endwhile;?>
```

And this is my change:

```
<div class="content row info active" id="panel2">
     <?php query_posts('p=35'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

```
<dl class="row content tabs small-6 large-centered columns" data-tab>

<dd><a href="#cabernetsauvignon"><span class="link">Cabernet Sauvignon</span></a></dd>
<dd><a href="#merlot"><span class="link">Merlot</span></a></dd>
<dd><a href="#chardonnay"><span class="link">Chardonnay</span></a></dd>
<dd><a href="#sauvignonblanc"><span class="link">Sauvignon Blanc</span></a></dd>
<dd><a href="#sauvignonblanc"><span class="link">Carmenere</span></a></dd></dl>

                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
             </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns txt">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div> 
    </div> 
            <?php endwhile;?>
```

How could i add a fifth element rightly...aligning this horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

`class="row` creates a new row, it should be probably a column / cell